# Preventing model update on cancel for angular-xeditable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

Im using [angular-xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form), On changing value of "editable-text" and pressing Cancel button "editable-text" value must revet back to previous one. in other word "editable-text" keeps updating Model even if Cancel button is pressed.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it, since Im using e-ng-change="onChange(field, $data)" in "editable-text" which is causing this behaviour, default behaviour of "editable-text" is fine